# General term to refer to acquiring knowledge of news or an event

Tags: word-usage, idioms, verb-usage

I am trying to find a way to refer to acquiring the knowledge of something new or to be aware of something that recently happened.

Usually we can say,

> I heard on the news...
>
> I read on the news...

or even besides news,

> I heard that your brother got a new job.
>
> I read that they are builiding a new house in front of your work.
>
> Didn't you hear what happened? There is this virus outbreak in China.

I am wondering whether is there a specific verb or expression I can use for this.

Sometimes I think I hear some people using to learn with this meaning, but I am uncertain whether it is correct.

> I learnt you'll become a father.
>
> Did you learn what is the team doing next year? They will play with a new jersey.
>
> I learnt today they are planning to build a new airport in the city.

Is this correct? otherwise, is there any way to refer to this?

Comment: We use various "verbs of perception" *(**hear, read, see**)* quite loosely in English for the general sense of "become aware of", so it's quite possible for someone to say *I **heard** you got married* even if they actually acquired that information by ***reading*** a Facebook post. But we use many other verbs with much the same sense, so *I **understand** you're emigrating* is just a slightly roundabout way of saying I'm *aware* that you intend to leave the country (but I may not have the faintest idea ***why***; I don't really "understand" the situation).

Comment: ...and *I **gather** you are to be a father*, for example, is an even more extreme ***metaphoric*** usage (not to mention ***gleaning** information*). All language is metaphor, as they say.

Comment: ...by the same token, ***to learn X*** can be used to mean ***to become aware of X*** as well as ***to be taught X.***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Great. So you mean that there are many verbs for this -many of them interchangeable depending the case-, but not a really a single verb that includes all of them, right? And if learn can be used to mean **_to become aware of X_**, that would be maybe the closest to a globar verb for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a single verb that includes all of them". But there are few (if any cases) in English of even *two* words having *exactly* the same meaning in all contexts, so you shouldn't assume that you could use ***to become aware of*** to replace every instance of the alternative verbs I've given above. Maybe you'll find some useful ideas by looking at the Wikipedia page for [epistemic modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality), but at the moment it's not clear to me exactly what you're asking, and what *kind* of answer you're looking for.